# The token was issued in the future

Tags: php, firebase-authentication

I created a function to log a user into the system. While I was using the system on my localhost, I had no problem logging into Firebase using this code:

```
public function login(string $email, string $password)
{
    $errors = [];
    try {
        $signInResult = $this->auth->signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password);
        $token = $signInResult->idToken();
        $decodedToken = $this->auth->verifyIdToken($token);
        $claims = $decodedToken->claims()->all();
        $member_id = $claims['user_id'];
```

However, after hosting the files on a web server, I found that the authentication does not occur, generating an exception on this line:

```
$decodedToken = $this->auth->verifyIdToken($token);
```

The exception is:

> 'Kreait\Firebase\Exception\Auth\FailedToVerifyToken: The value 'eyJhbGciOiJSUzI...' is not a verified ID token: - - The token was issued in the future in ...'

I'm using these dependency versions:

- "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.34
- "kreait/firebase-php": "^6.9.6",
- "firebase/php-jwt": "6.7.0",
- "google/auth": "^1.25",
- "kreait/firebase-tokens": "^3.0.3
- "php": "^8.0

How do I fix this error?

Comment: Is the date and time on the server correct?

Comment: yes. Google's 2-factor authentication in cPanel works perfectly. I believe that if the server's time was incorrect, it wouldn't work.